# Angularjs app stops loading resources after a while

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat

I have a standard angularjs app that routes to different pages with their own controllers. My problem is that after a while using it the resources(images and videos) stop loading.
In Chrome devtools their status is listed as pending, size is listed as 0B and the time as pending. There are no errors in the console and my own debugging hasn't brought up anything else.

I have never worked with angularjs before, but I couldn't find anything online either(only results were resources not loading from the start).

The app is running on tomcat 8.0.37 and using angularjs v1.2.5

EDIT : The main page the ngView is on is a jsp which is why tomcat is used, unforunately I am not able to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't recommend use Tomcat for JS frameworks. Tomcat has a lot of options like `multipleFileSize`and they will occur a lot problems when your project published.

Simply you can use [HTTP-SERVER](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) for run your project.

If your project is complex you can use [GRUNT](http://gruntjs.com/) or [GULP](http://gulpjs.com/).

Comment: @Vinc If you are using AngularJs(or other front end framework) you need to clean up it from Java Servlet!